# How to query children by post name/slug

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query

It appears that I can only use an ID for the param `post_parent` whether in `WP_Query` or `get_children`

Is there a way to query for children via postnames which are more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `get_page_by_path()` function ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path)).

So, something like:

```
$mypage = get_page_by_path( 'page-slug' );

$mypageid = ( $mypage ? $mypage->ID : '0' );
```

Then, the `post_parent` argument becomes:

`'post_parent' => $mypageid`